# Symfony JWT Bundle and form authentication

Tags: symfony, security, lexikjwtauthbundle

When configuring the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle I just need to set up the security.yml with these settings:

```
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login: # <-- my question is about this
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

There is no reference to the database or the user class. How does the bundle know how to authenticate the user when making this request?

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe -d _password=test`

I looked into the bundle's source code but I couldn't find any reference about `_username`. Is this a Symfony built-in security system?

Comment: Your firewall `login` must have a `provider`